# Android: Able to send/receive files through Socket.IO (AndroidAsync)?

Tags: android, socket.io, file-transfer, androidasync-koush

Is it possible to send/receive files through a `Socket.IO` connection using koush's `AndroidAsync` client?

If there isn't a direct way, any workarounds?

Thanks in advance!